# Saving a binary file with HyperTerminal

Tags: serial-port, binary-files, hyperterminal

I have an embedded platform that is connected to my Windows PC via the serial connection. The embedded application sends 532 bytes through the connection. Using HyperTerminal, I am able to see the incoming (non-text) characters in the terminal window. However, I am trying to save the stream as a binary file. The problem is that when I choose to 'Receive File...', the dialog that opens (after asking for a file name and location) does not have a *stop* button, so my only option for stopping the reception is through *canceling*, which discards the captured data.

It appears that although I am not sending pure text, I can use the 'Capture Text...' menu. Then, I can manually terminate the reception of data. There are two problems, though - first, the new data is appended to the existing file (if there is one), and not replacing it. Second, the terminal adds a 0xff byte at the end of the file (signaling end of text file).

So, how do I save a binary stream to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper Terminal is not a correct choice in this case. It probably wants a [protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms818664.aspx) like xmodem or zmodem used for the data, which your device seems not to send.

As an alternative, you can try to use a recent [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) version and use its logging.

Comment: Thanks, @Turbo J. It looks like PuTTY is able to do what is harder to get with Hyper Terminal. Now I have to get to the source code and try to see if I can isolate the parts that communicate with the COM port and log it.